# Retained self not working inside block statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to set the alpha of a label, inside a block statement and therefore I'm calling self. As I understand it, I can't call self directly from within a block statement, so I have to make a reference of self first.

This is the code I have, but it's not working:

```
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    __weak UILabel *weakSelf = self.errorLabel;
    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType options:NULL completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
         if (!granted) {
             [weakSelf setAlpha:0.0f];
         } 
     }];
```

Any ideas of what might be the problem?

**UPDATE 1**

I 've also tried to only reference self, but with no luck:

```
self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    __weak FrontPageViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType options:NULL completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
         if (!granted) {
             [weakSelf.errorLabel setAlpha:0.0f];
         } 
     }];
```

**UPDATE 2**

Just checked if error label is nil and it doesn't seem to be:

```
if (self.errorLabel != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Errorlabel is not nil"); //Errorlabel is not nil
}
```

**CAUSE OF ERROR**

The error was that I had this code right after I wanted to fade out the label:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
    //self.errorLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL success){
}];
```

I don't fully understand why this should cause trouble?

Comment: If granted is `NO` wouldn't you want your errorLabel's alpha to be 1.0?

Comment: Ya, I would want it to be 1, but for now I just want it to change. Just checked error label (see above) and it's not nil.

Comment: try set alpha outside block, is it works?

Comment: Tried that and it works fine. I'm kind of mystified over this. Seems so weird.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `setAlpha:` line and when it hits the breakpoint `po weakSelf` for a description. Also make sure the completion handler is called on the main thread. Sometime `UIKit` throws out(ignores) calls like this on a background thread.

Comment: You can reference `self` inside a block statement, if your block will be released automatically at some point. What you can't do is set your block as a property of `self` and then refer to `self` inside the block. That creates a retain cycle.

Comment: So you are saying that I can reference "self" inside the block statement? I've tried that as well and there is no effect there either. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do I make sure that the completion handler is called on the main thread?

Comment: Quick thread check like so: `NSLog(@"Is main thread = %@",(dispatch_get_main_queue() == dispatch_get_current_queue())?@"YES":@"NO");`

Comment: I get "Is main thread = NO", but I also get that dispatch_get_current_queue is deprecated in iOS 6. Do you think it's not running on the main thread? Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: `dispatch_get_current_queue()` should only be used for debugging. That subject itself is interesting reading. But it is still a useful debugging tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure **all your UI calls** are made from the main thread. This includes any `animateWith...` calls. The quickest way is to simply wrap them in a dispatch block, like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                     animations:^{
                         self.errorLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
});
```

If you are unsure if your code is running on the main thread you can debug with the following statement.

```
NSLog(@"Is main thread = %@",(dispatch_get_main_queue() == dispatch_get_current_queue())?@"YES":@"NO");
```

Always lookout for completion handlers on asynchronous network APIs. Make sure their documentation says the completion handler will be called on the main thread. If it doesn't, play it safe and transfer any UI related work to the main thread.

Comment: Still no working. Even weirder, if I test the alpha after this statement, like this: NSLog(@"Alpha: %f", self.errorLabel.alpha); It gives me 0. But the label is still there!

Comment: Sometimes it does seem to remove the label. Once or twice every 10 runs. Why is this weird thing happening?

Comment: I found the error. I don't fully understand it though. I've posted it above.

Comment: Your entire `animateWith...` should be called on the main thread. When you make a UI call on a background thread it screws things up just like you're describing. You can just put the whole animation call in the dispatch block, and it will be performed on the main thread.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. If you edit your answer with what you just wrote, I'll check it off. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
__block __weak UILabel *weakSelf = self.errorLabel;
```

Comment: Nope still not working. When I do: NSLog(@"Errorlabel is not nil: %@", weakSelf.text); it gives me the title of the label, so it should be hooked up correctly. What is going on here?

Comment: Is the object still alive when the block is executed?

Comment: It's an IBOutlet, so it certainly should be.